# Key repeat - removal of modifier

Tags: gvim

Using GVIM, I sometimes hold ctrl-d to page-down a lot, and I let go of ctrl first (unintentionally and momentarily) and cause a line to be deleted b/c an additional 'd' without 'ctrl' is sent. What is the expected behavior on different operating systems? I remember testing this a while back and seeing MacOS not perform a repeat of 'd', but now I see it does. Is there a standard resolution to this issue? Is it a GVIM issue?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in the title, but a possible work around for your specific issue could be to use `ctrl-f` to page down instead of `ctrl-d`.  That way, the worst case scenario if you accidentally let go of the control key is that you find the next 'f' on the line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's GVim. This happens in the Linux terminal too. It may be OS-dependent, but I suspect it's more likely that you can count on the next key repeat of <kbd>d</kbd> to be interpreted as <kbd>d</kbd> and not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

What to do? Pak's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> suggestion is a good one (`:help pagedown`). Faster, too. You could also consider binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, which would leave you moving down one line at a time if you lift up the wrong key. (I use that to move between splits, but it might work for you).